# How to build a regular expression from predefined blocks

Tags: python, regex

I want to build a regular expression based on a template and a set of predefined blocks, and using string.Template for the substitution.

For example:

- template: `/data/${year}_${month}_${day}/${year}${month}${day}_${type}_${id}.dat`
- blocks:

  - day:    `(?P<day>\d{2})`
  - month:  `(?P<month>\d{2})`
  - year:   `(?P<year>\d{4})`
  - type:   `(?P<typechar>[BDPCLNIYSQJ])`
  - id:     `(?P<id>\d{8})`

---

```
>>> string.Template(template).safe_substitute(blocks)

/data/(?P<year>\d{4})_(?P<month>\d{2})_(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})_(?P<typechar>[BDPCLNIYSQJ])_(?P<id>\d{8}).dat
```

The problem is with duplicated name groups, which are not accepted in the regular expression.

I'm looking either for a way to correct the template (before or after the substitution), a way to trick re to swallow the duplicates, or a complete new approach to the problem.

Comment: You can give them different name, no?

Comment: the idea is to be able to reuse blocks without changing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following a friend's advice, I found a way to achieve the desired result.

The idea is to modify the template string to eliminate duplicate vars before substituting the regex blocks. In fact it's not removing the duplicates but replacing them with a reference to the first one with the (?P=name) syntax. This way you force the contents to be the same everywhere you use that block.

I will assume the regex groupname is the same as the template block name. This is not true in the question example, but it can be changed without any problem.

To transform the duplicates I use the following function:

```
>>> def remove_duplicate_blocks(template):
        regex = '\$\{([\w]+)\}'
        def alt_seen(matchobj):
            x = matchobj.group(1)
            if x not in seen and not seen_add(x): return '${%s}' % x
            else: return '(?P=%s)' % x
        seen = set()
        seen_add = seen.add
        return re.sub(regex, alt_seen, template)
```

which returns the transformed template without duplicates and enforcing all similar blocks to have the same content.

Afterwards it's just a matter of replacing the blocks

```
>>> unique_blocks_template = remove_duplicate_blocks(template)
>>> print unique_blocks_template
/data/${year}_${month}_${day}/(?P=year)(?P=month)(?P=day)_${type}_${id}.dat

>>> string.Template(unique_blocks_template).safe_substitute(blocks)
'/data/(?P<year>\\d{4})_(?P<month>\\d{2})_(?P<day>\\d{2})/(?P=year)(?P=month)(?P=day)_(?P<type>[BDPCLNIYSQJ])_(?P<id>\\d{8}).dat'
```

Not mentioned in the question, but the same original template can also be used to reconstruct the string we want to match with the regex, which is the original aim of this code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Python but both PCRE and Perl support (?(DEFINE)...) construction. So you can use something like this

```
(?x) 
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<date>        (?&long_date) | (?&short_date))
    (?<long_date>   (?&year) _ (?&month) _ (?&day) _ (?&type) _ (?&id))
    (?<short_date>  (?&year) _ (?&month) _ (?&day))
    (?<day>         \d{2})
    (?<month>       \d{2})
    (?<year>        \d{4})
    (?<type>        [BDPCLNIYSQJ])
    (?<id>          \d{8})
)
(?&date)
```

I've used "x" modifier (?x) just to make the regex more readable (now whitespaces inside the regex are ignored).

> A "conditional group" of the form (?(DEFINE)...) can be used to define
>   groups (named and numbered) that are never evaluated inline, but can
>   be called as "subroutines" from elsewhere. In effect, the DEFINE
>   condition is always false. There may be only one alternative in such a
>   group.

http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt

Comment: It would seem a proper way to do it, but unfortunately python's re does not seem to support this kind of constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the ?P name elements.
ie

```
day: (?P<name>\d{2})
```

becomes

```
day: (\d{2})
```

I've never used the ?P feature before tbh

Your regexp template idea is good though!

Comment: The ?P elements are named (as in "(?P<day>\d{2})"), as I would like to access the matched group by name. since there is no a priori grouping, I need to use those names to know what I'm getting.

Comment: ok then, apply the template twice, I'll try and do as an answer this comment box makes it difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

apply the template twice, once to set the name and then use the output to make the final regexp

```
day='(?P<$dayname>\d{2})'
d=dict(dayname='day_start')
Template(day).safe_substitute(d)
```

repeat for all the names you need then feed them all into your final template which uses day1 day2 etc

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would require me to supply distinct names for each of the regex name appeareances, sort to say. The idea is for this to require no extra input than blocks.